# Query last 12 months in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I need to query the last 12months records from a datatable, but cant figure out what the syntax is in VB.NET.

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio the following query works:

```
[MyTable] >= dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-12,0)
```

How can I achieve this in VB.NET?

My query is simple:

```
Dim Result As Integer = (From k In Model.Case
                         Join p In Model.Company ON k.Id_Case Equals p.Id_Case
                         Where k.EndingDate **Insert Code Here**).Count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time never use Vb, please understand the pseudo code:

```
dim dtRange = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)
'dim dtRange = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-12) 'For UTC time

Dim Result As Integer = (From k In Model.Case
                         Join p In Model.Company ON k.Id_Case Equals p.Id_Case
                         Where k.EndingDate >= dtRange).Count()
```